# One time click and delete button state persistance

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Let's say I have the following scenario.
I have a page full of posts. For each post I have a button that adds a point to the model's points variable through an ajax request. I want the user to click that button, add the point, delete the button from the DOM using jQuery and make that removal persistent throughout the session. So a refresh doesn't make the button reappear.

My problem is the last part, making that button 'stay removed'. I know http is stateless and I've got to maintain the state somewhere so I've thought about adding a field in the database, using localstorage/localsession or django session.

Which method would be the most appropriate ? Are there other ways?

Thank you for your time and please tell me if I may have missed any similar question and I'll delete this one right away.

Comment: this question is a little vague. There are virtually infinite ways to save a view state

Comment: yes, what @godmode said. As it stands, this question is unanswerable because it's both opinion based and too broad. Please take a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: if all you're storing is whether a button has already been clicked, and thus shouldn't be on the page I would use `JSON.stringify` and object and store it in `sessionStorage`. Then on page load `JSON.parse(sessionStorage.viewState)`

Comment: Sessions or Cookies are the most obvious options, then you could use local storage, in memory databases.......

Comment: @godmode I tried to describe it the best I could. But yes, that's all I'm storing and I was wondering what's the best way to go about it. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option, though I don't claim it is the best!

Using the javascript library simplestorage for cross browser compatibility: https://github.com/andris9/simpleStorage

Give each of your buttons a unique id and the same class, eg:

```
<button id="points_123" class="add_points">Add Point</button>
```

Then in your javascript:
      // make record of buttons clicked
      $(".add_points").on("click", function() {

```
      simpleStorage.set(this.id, 1);

  });

  // when loading page, hide buttons already clicked
  // (even to hide everything by default and then show ones not clicked)
  $(".add_points").each(function() {
      var clicked = simpleStorage.get(this.id);
      if (clicked > 0) {
         $(this).hide();
      }

  });
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/phoebebright/73bv7b6r/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is the method I picked, except hiding everything by default and then showing the not clicked buttons.